# call parent component function from child component using react router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, react-router, react-hooks

I am working on reactJS application where I want to pass parent component's props to child component so that child component can call/trigger the function which is defined in parent component. But the below code is not working for me:

**index.tsx**

```
export const history = createHistory.createBrowserHistory();

const AppRouter = ({alert,someFunction}) => (
    
    <Router history={history}>
        <div>
            <Layout>
                <Route path="/" exact render={(props) => (<Home alert={alert} someFunction={someFunction} {...props}/>)} />
            </Layout>
        </div>
    </Router>
);

export default withAlert()(AppRouter);
```

**Layout.tsx**

```
 export interface LayoutProps {
        children?: React.ReactNode;
    }
    
    export class Layout extends React.Component<LayoutProps,{IsLoading: boolean},{alert,someFunction}> {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            // Bind the this context to the handler function
            this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
            // Set some state
            this.state = {
                IsLoading: false
            };
        }
    
        public render() {
    
            const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
                // checking isValidElement is the safe way and avoids a typescript error too
                const props = { alert, action:this.handler };
                if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
                    return React.cloneElement(child, { alert, someFunction: () => this.setState({ IsLoading: true }) });
                }
                return child;
            });
    
            return <div className='app-container'>
                <div className='row content-container'>
                    <NavMenu />
                </div>
            <div className='container-fluid' style={{marginLeft:"74px",marginTop: "-10px"}}>
               {childrenWithProps}
            </div></div>;
        }
    // NEED to Call this handler function OR someFunction from child component
        handler() {
            console.log('handler_ckick');
            this.setState({
                IsLoading: true
             });
        }
    }
```

**child.tsx(Home.tsx)**

```
interface IChildComponentProps  {
    
}

interface PassedProps  {
    alert: any
}
interface AddO3DataState {
    DateStr: string;
  }

export class Home extends React.Component<IChildComponentProps & PassedProps, AddO3DataState> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            Date: new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]            
        };
        // This binding is necessary to make "this" work in the callback
        this.doParentToggleFromChild = this.doParentToggleFromChild.bind(this);
    }

    doParentToggleFromChild(){
        this.props.someFunction();
      }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think the way that you are going about this is the right way, but there are pieces missing from your code so it's hard for me to make specific recommendations.  As it stands now, you call the same `someFunction` regardless of which child is clicked, so you could achieve the same effect by having a single div with `onClick={() => someFunction()}` and put all children inside of it.  Additionally your concerns with function binding basically go away if you switch to function components and arrow functions as arrow functions bind explicitly.

Comment: @LindaPaiste hey.. thanks for ur comment, yes this is the current setup available with me for Layout(master) and Home(child) component. And yes I need this same function for all the children but in a way so that it would get triggered from child itself (based on some child event I would like to call this parent function so that it will do the needful).... u can correct me if m wrong in my understanding for getting the expected outcome.